# tasm program for inserting substring into main string

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need help with this assembly language program because I' m new to ALP' s. 
Here is the problem:
Write an assembly language program to insert substring into main string 
I'm using tasm(not sure if it is of any help)
I tried it. But I'm getting [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD0Nv.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, paste here source code of your program, it will be more convenient then image. Also, the image your provided contains the source code, not the errors.

Comment: You can't take the contents of `msg1` and place it at `msg2` like that. You could reserve some space at `msg2` and copy the string at runtime, or you could make `msg1` an _equate_ (using `EQU` or whatever directive your assembler supports).

Comment: Note that you can't make `msg1` an equate if you need to take its address somewhere in your code.

Comment: You didn't *really* try, you just take the conventional "show a string" example and changed the string. We need a proof of work or this is just cheating. Are you having troubles with finding an algorithm or implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any (directly visible) errors in that png.

You didn't do any "insert substring into main", you have only "display string msg2" in your code.

And I wouldn't even dare to execute that, as it doesn't exit correctly, so the (undefined) content of memory after your code will start to execute, probably causing all sorts of weird behaviour.

So now do:

1. add the exit int 21h service call (see your documentation about DOS `int 21h`, how to call "exit program" function of it). (after that you may want to compile it, and run, to verify it really does display string at msg2 memory correctly).
2. realize how the strings are stored in memory, they are not a virtual thing in the air, computer can process only numbers, so they must somehow conform this. After that prepare buffer of memory long enough to hold final modified string.
3. define what are the inputs of program (main string, and the sub string to be inserted, and how do you define where it gets inserted)
4. write code inserting substring into main string, using the big buffer to write the final string
5. reuse that display you have now to show the output
6. exit ;)